# Why does this code to play a sound using Python and Pygame on mac not load the file and crash?

Tags: macos, python-3.x, audio, pygame

I have looked at several questions on this site and multiple other resources and found this code that can be used to play a sound with pygame, but I have been having some issues with it.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

I have tried two files ("sound.wav' and 'sound.mp3'), as well as single and double quotes, and it still doesn't work. When I try the path of the files, Python crashes. Is there something I can change in or add to this code to make it work, and if not, is there another solution?

The error I get says that it can't load the file.

EDIT: Now it is crashing no matter what I pass to pygame.mixer.Sound(), saying Python quit unexpectedly.

Comment: You should probably try to reinstall pygame. Why can't you install pip properly? What error do you have?

Comment: I reinstalled pygame and installed Pip. Apparently, there was a problem with my command line tools, but with some deleting/reinstallation of applications and a restart, things started working again. However, the sounds are still not working.

Answer (score 1):

In pygame you can't use relative file paths unless you use os.

```
import pygame,os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
pygame.init()
song = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(dir,'./sound.wav'))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
song.play()
while True:
    clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: When I do that, it says "Python quit unexpectedly"

Comment: @TrumpetDude Looked it up and tried it out, try converting your file to .ogg and using this one. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

using pygame to play sound, make sure that your code contains stop music code as well, if your code only contains start music then it python will not play that sound.

example.

```
from pygame import mixer

mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("song.mp3")
mixer.music.set_volume("0.5")
mixer.music.play()
```

#comment ::: if you have only this code then your sound will not be played you #should add code for stop it at any point like brlow..

```
st = input("type s to stop")
if(st == "s"):
   mixer.music.stop()
```

#now this code will work